# "Terminating" an instance of a class

Tags: c#, oop, kinect

Good day eh.

I'm working on a C# project where we take the Microsoft Kinect, use it to track a person who performs a series of jumps, and take the skeleton generated for calculations of the knee angles.

Last night when we were testing subjects, I thought it'd be nice to have a control on the program that you could click and end the "current" test subject's output file, then start another subject. To track the skeleton to begin with, we created a tracker object of the class Tracker that is found in the Kinect for Windows SDK. This then initiates all of the logic that does the tracking and output. However, when we "close" the first subject's output, we seem to only be closing the file, not the actual instance of the tracker object. This causes the tracker to remain "open", existing alongside the new instance of the tracker object that we've created for the new test subject, using double the computational resources and causing an unacceptable degradation in performance.

How do I "close" the first instance of the tracker object?

If you guys need code to examine, let me know; I didn't include it because it's impractically long to post on here.

EDIT:

Here's at least some of the code. We have the "Start" event (for the first test subject), the "Next Subject" event (for subsequent test subjects), and the "tracker" code.

Next Subject: (this is the one where we need to make the changes)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// stops "old" file and graph streams, closes file, launches dialog for new subject and starts 
    /// stream up again
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void buttonNextSubject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Ask the user if they're sure they want to stop the current stream
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to stop the stream and start a new one?", "New Subject", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK){
            if (fileCheck == true)
            {
                tracker.outputFile.closeFiles();
                //SHUT DOWN OLD TRACKER HERE
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }


        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Subject"; //Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; //Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; //Filter files by extension
        //Show save file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        buttonStart.IsEnabled = false;
        buttonPause.IsEnabled = true;
        buttonResume.IsEnabled = false;
        fileCheck = true;

        //Start Kinect- If no sensor, ask to connect one and exit.
        try
        {
            this.sensor.Start();
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            this.sensor = null;
            //display error message here
            MessageBox.Show("No Kinect sensor found. Please connect one and restart the application", "*****ERROR*****");
        }
        sensor.ElevationAngle = 0;
        tracker = new Tracker(sensor, this, dlg.FileName);
    }
}
```

The tracker object/Tracker class:

```
    internal class Tracker{
        private Skeleton[] skeletons = null;
        private MainWindow window;
        public Class1 outputFile;
        public string fn;
        public Tracker(KinectSensor sensor, MainWindow win, string fileName){                
                //Connect the skeleton frame handler and enable skeleton tracking
                sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += SensorSkeletonFrameReady;
                sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
                sensor.ColorFrameReady += SensorColorFrameReady;
                sensor.ColorStream.Enable();
                window = win;                
                outputFile = new Class1(fileName);
                fn = fileName;
                window.graphTickPen2.DashStyle = System.Windows.Media.DashStyles.Dash;
        }
```

Finally, the "Start" event that I based the "Next Subject" event off of:

```
    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){           
        // Configure save file dialog box
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "Default"; // Default file name
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension
        // Show save file dialog box
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        buttonStart.IsEnabled = false;
        buttonPause.IsEnabled = true;
        buttonResume.IsEnabled = false;
        fileCheck = true;
        //Create drawing group
        this.drawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
        this.leftLegDrawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
        this.rightLegDrawingGroup = new DrawingGroup();
        //Create image source for WPF control
        this.imageSource = new DrawingImage(this.drawingGroup);
        this.leftLegBoxImageSource = new DrawingImage(this.leftLegDrawingGroup);
        this.rightLegBoxImageSource = new DrawingImage(this.rightLegDrawingGroup);
        leftLegColorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(483, 152, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
        rightLegColorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(483, 152, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
        colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(640, 480, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
        colorPixels = new byte[this.sensor.ColorStream.FramePixelDataLength];           
        //Start Kinect- If no sensor, ask to connect one and exit.
        try{
            this.sensor.Start();
        }
        catch (IOException){
            this.sensor = null;
            //display error message here
            MessageBox.Show("No Kinect sensor found. Please connect one and restart the application", "*****ERROR*****");
        }
        sensor.ElevationAngle = 0;            
        tracker = new Tracker(sensor, this, dlg.FileName);
    }
```

Comment: When you help someone on coding problems, do you not ask them to show you their code? OF COURSE WE NEED TO SEE CODE!!!! (only post what is required for the community to help you and not the whole project)

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever heard of `.dispose()` to "terminate an instance of a class" aka, dispose of it's resource allocation.

Answer (score 0):

as a peek into the Kinect API would have told you,
 you use KinectSensor.Stop() in exactly the way you would think

[reference to Kinect API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensor_members.aspx)

Or is your problem that this function does not do what is referenced to do?

EDIT: as I now understand the problem, you can just un-subscribe the tracker from the sensor like so:

```
sensor.SkeletonFrameReady -= tracker.SensorSkeletonFrameReady;
sensor.ColorFrameReady -= tracker.SensorColorFrameReady;
```

You could also simply set the events in the sensor to null, which will amount to the same (except it will unsubscribe any event handlers from that event)

```
sensor.SkeletonFrameReady = null;
sensor.ColorFrameReady = null;
```

In this example, this might be easier (since there will be no problems when tracker is not instantiated and such), if you really only have the tracker listening to the sensor's streams

Comment: Problem is, we don't want to "stop" the sensor if we can help it.

Comment: could you not then solve the problem by un-subscribing that tracker from the given sensor?

editing my answer for an example in a sec